# Malware injecting code into my Dojo/WebSocket app: how prevent?

Tags: javascript, browser, dojo, websocket, malware

I've written a web UI for an embedded product, built on Dojo and using WebSockets to communicate back to the device. It works well and reliably on most browsers, but on a number of customer machines the WebSockets have been unable to connect. I've finally been able to see the problem on a customer machine, and it's a SecurityError thrown in some JavaScript that's trying to access the localStorage. Here's the kicker: the faulty code is actually from superfish.com, and is being injected into my web app by a tool installed on the customer machine.

Further investigation implies that the culprit is actually the Sendori "browser helper" tool, which is marketed as a shopping assistant but actually does web ad replacement by using a tool from Superfish. (Sidebar: while diagnosing this I spent a couple of hours trying to get Sendori/Superfish installed on my browser. I failed, because Googling "Sendori" and/or "superfish" produced hundreds of "Remove Sendori" pages, but not a single "Install Sendori" page. I guess nobody really wants this on their machine.)

The Sendory/Superfish code is somehow being added after my </html> tag:

```
... (my page) ...
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sendori.com/js/inlinekeywords.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sendori.com/js/pconfig.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sndpID = '99999';
var sndgID = '{59AD66B3-91A0-4FEC-8E84-160E95E1FF89}';
var mseEntry = 0;
var msSecurityFlag = 1;
var programData = 'Sendori';
....
```

My one hope is that my initial loader DOES execute before any of the injected code, which means I may be able to knock it out before it kicks in.

So, how can I prevent the malicious code from messing up my code? Yes, I can probably uninstall Sendori from this customer's machine (although my first attempt failed), but then there's all the other customers with the same problem who don't even know Sendori is there.

Edit: it's kind of entertaining that I asked this question just BEFORE the Lenovo/Superfish issue exploded.

Comment: Hmmm.  It might depend upon when the code is being added and how it is being inserted.  I wonder if you could hook `.appendChild` at the DOM level and inspect what is being inserted and skip the actual appendChild operation if the contents are a script tag from `sendori.com`?  If this was a possibility, then you could keep their code from ever getting inserted in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that if the browser is compromised, there is little you can do about it.

Still... here is a crazy idea...

If the malware is appending the JS at the end of the document... try to attach a `<!--` at the end of your doucument:

Your document is like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Test</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when the malware runs, it just appends scripts at the end:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Test</b>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    alert('script added');
</script>
```

The idea is that you end the document with an open comment:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Test</b>
    </body>
</html>
<!--
```

So whatever is appended, it is commented out:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Test</b>
    </body>
</html>
<!--
<script>
    alert('script added');
</script>
```

I think it should not affect your document (I still find unbelievable the fact that the browser is executing things out of the `html` tag).

If the plugin is smarter and it is adding the code after the `</html>` tag... then this solution won't work, but I think is worth to try. It all boils down to determine how smart is the malware when parsing the document and inserting its trash. But I think that if is adding things at the end, it is because is not doing any parsing at all.

If it is finding the `</html>` tag, you can try to do something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Test</b>
    </body>
<!-- 
</html>
-->
</html>
<!-- 
</html>
```

That will cause the malware to add the trash in the commented out areas right after the fake `</html>` tags. There is a fake one if the malware is reading from the top, and another fake one if it is reading from the bottom.

Now, if the malware actually parses the HTML document properly... well I am not sure there is solution for that.

Comment: I'm definitely gonna try this one. There's strong circumstantial evidence that the attacker is NOT parsing the page, because if he* were parsing the page then a) he'd break on badly structured pages, and b) he'd probably insert his code somewhere else (e.g. the &lt;head&gt;).

Comment: *Apologies to women programmers for my use of "he", but it's still true that most malicious programmers are male. (Someday this will no longer be true; I don't know if I should welcome it, or fear it.)

Comment: That worked: the injected code is now commented out. My app still doesn't work, though... I'll have to figure out where else it is breaking on this machine.

Comment: Nice. I will consider adding it to my pages as well.

Comment: Hey, did you finally find what was preventing your page from work?

Comment: No, didn't. It's quite rare, though, and seems pretty clearly to be something strange with the users' systems, so we're currently moving onto other issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent code from running, because from the JS engine's point of view, running it is what you want - else you would not have sent it. The JS engine does not know, the code was inserted by a third party.

Basically, Sendori is malware - and with a malware-infested browser, all chances of a sane execution environment are off. THe problem is on the client side - you can't fix it from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can block cross domain origins for resources using the "Same Origin Policy"

This means that any resources that do not originate on your server will not be loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header

Comment: This won't block the scripts in question from loading themselves and it won't stop the error the script is causing.  It is unclear how this helps solve this problem.

Comment: These tools would allow me to specify whether my web resources could be used in other domains. There doesn't seem to be a mechanism for specifying whether other domains' resources can be used in MY domain. So, this doesn't seem pertinent.

Comment: Check the chart at the top of "Definition of an origin" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy . Mozilla claims it will prevent the browser from requesting outside content.